# translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints and IB

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

In UIView.h you can read the following:

```
/* by default, the autoresizing mask on a view gives rise to constraints 
   that fully determine the view's position.  Any constraints you set on 
   the view are likely to conflict with autoresizing constraints, 
   so you must turn off this property first. IB will turn it off for you.
 */
- (BOOL)translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // Default YES
```

So it means that when you create a `UIView` from a xib, `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` should be set to `NO`.

However, when I create a view form a xib using `[[UINib nibWithNibName:nibName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil]`, `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `YES`.

Any idea why?

Comment: If you set checkmark  AutoLauOut in nib then translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints will be set

Comment: The checkbox "Use Autolayout" in my xib file is already checked.

Comment: @MartinMoizard, did you found out the answer yet?

Comment: @courteous - No, still a mystery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug already filed in Apple's bug reporter. It should be fixed in a future release.